# «Юная Мэри Поппинс», девочка выпала с окна. Мэри пишется в кавычках?

Tags: существительные

Юная «Мэри Поппинс».... девочка выпала с окна... Употребляется в кавычках?

Comment: Корректно: Выпала ИЗ окна

Comment: написание Мэри Поппинс в кавычках – корректное?

Comment: По основному правилу кавычки не нужны, однако, чтобы дать точный ответ, нужен более широкий контекст.

Comment: Девочка взяла зонтик, по примеру Поппинс, героини книги, и шагнула из окна.....

Comment: Кавычки как раз указывают на то, что имя употреблено необычно, здесь оно в качестве нарицательного. Чтобы читателю было ясно, что речь идет не о сказочной героине.

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки здесь по правилам необязательны, см., например, В. В. Маяковский "Сергею Есенину"

> Чтобы разнеслась бездарнейшая погань,
>   раздувая темь пиджачных парусов,
>   чтобы врассыпную разбежался **[Коган](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%9F%D1%91%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)**,
>   встреченных увеча пиками усов.

Другое дело, что тема в этическом плане довольно скользкая, и не хочется мешать, сказочный персонаж и возможную трагедию, так что я бы всё-таки поставил.

Comment: С точки зрения этики, ставь кавычки или нет - все равно неэтично. Черный юмор.

Comment: @М_Г согласен, но так хотя бы появляется некоторая отстранённость, восприятие с точки зрения того ребёнка "девочка решила, что она Мэри Поппинс и полетела из окна с зонтиком". В то время как в варианте без кавычек получается, что-то вроде "То же мне Мэри Поппинс с нашего двора из окон прыгает".

Comment: (1)  Роль Когана в жизни Есенина? (2) У Маяковского Коган выступает как имя нарицательное?

Comment: @М_Г Нарицательное, о чём прямо писал Маяковский в статье "Как делать стихи?", - "Коган становится, таким образом, собирательным, что дает ему возможность бежать врассыпную, а усы превращаются в пики, а чтобы эту пиковость усугубить, валяются кругом искалеченные усами".